# DropDownList postback never finishes on iPad

Tags: iphone, asp.net

I've seen several posts about DropDownLists getting cleared, or events not getting fired, but they don't seem to match this situation.

I've got (well I've reduced the problem to) a very simple asp.net website, a master page with a content page.  The content page has a single DropDownList with AutoPostback set to True.  The code behind updates a Label with the list's selected value.  Not using UpdatePanel or AJAX (though I tried using them and I get exactly the same results).  It's an intranet site using Windows authentication.

It works fine on IE and Chrome, but every time I try it on my iPad it just sits and spins.  The postback appears to be happening, but either nothing's coming back (or being accepted) from the server, or the client just doesn't know how to finish things up, or I don't know what.

Sorry if this seems vague but I've spent two hours on Google and haven't come up with anything other than the fact that a simple page like this should work fine on an iPad, so I'm a little punchy.

Anybody got any pointers or ideas?

**EDIT**: Running this page through the remote web access portal my company uses, it works fine.  So this may be an authentication problem between the iPad and IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I have an answer but do you have the issue if you remove the DropDownList?  If you need to build the list based on data maybe you could use a asp:repeater and build a html select list.